# Does it make sense to serve web resources directly from an assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Does it ever make sense to store things like images, scripts and what not inside of an assembly (for ease of portability), and then write a custom routing engine that would serve up this information? Alternatively, would it make sense to store the resources in an assembly, but then save them to disk before the first request?

I'm wondering about what is the best way to organize web resources that should be scoped to various modules. Thoughts?

Comment: It all depends on what context. compiling to an assembly is +1 portabilty but -1 for ease of maintenance. It's probably quicker loading static content from IIS then compiling and having it go through .net pipeline.

Comment: What is a good granular solution for managing resources you think?

Comment: straight from the web server, perhaps as a seperate app  if they are shared across various app. You get browser caching of those resources, which ultimately improves each apps performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that storing data as embedded resource helps to load all that with assembly.
This will be faster then load all files one by one.

Disk operations is expensive. Load files from assembly will be better solution.